# How to read a text file which is added to project before complilation?

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone-8

I have such problem.

I have text file. I'd like to add it into my project and then read it. This file is Lua script. I read, that I can read it and save in IsolatedStorage. But I have several problems:

I'm writing in C#, XNA 4.0, Windows Phone 8 SDK. In SDK there is no classes like 'Application' (System.Windows - there is no such namespace)

There is no 'ResourceReader' class (There is no ResourceReader class in System.Resource namespace)

I'm reading stackoverflow tips, but they are all not working in my case.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please be clearer about what you are trying to do.

Comment: He added a text file as a resource to the project and what to read it. I think he was quite clear on that.

Comment: I'd like to read a text file, which is added to project, and save it in IsolatedStorage of my app.

Comment: Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163455/windows-phone-7-crash-when-accessing-directory/15170426#15170426 - you need `TitleContainer`

Answer (score 0):

[How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

And had references to the assemblies you need in case you can't find that added to the project already.

Comment: Yes. It does not allow direct file/folder access. You should use `TitleContainer` to get files contained in the xap.

Comment: Always learning thanks. Someone else needs to help the OP then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163455/windows-phone-7-crash-when-accessing-directory/15170426#15170426 I basically explain everything here.